# FontAwesome typescript intellisense in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, font-awesome, typescript-typings

`IconDefinition` import was found by autocomplete (`ctrl + space`) but the individual icons are not. Am I missing some kind of configuration here?

Followed the instructions https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome for `npm`. Angular was built with latest CLI version (ng v8) using `ng new`.

All icons and types are present under `node_modules\@fortawesome\free-solid-svg-icons`

For example: `node_modules\@fortawesome\free-solid-svg-icons\faSearch.d.ts`

TS: 3.5.3

VSCode: 1.41.1

[image]

**UPDATE**

Seems to be also temperamental for `rxjs` operators and other module imports

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the same still, but I used like this in my old project.

**component**

```
import { faAngleDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
faAngleDown = faAngleDown;
```

**app.module**

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
```

Comment: Thanks. Done all that, seems to be any new modules added it can't auto complete until I manually do it once myself.